# Where is SQL Configuration Manager in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I just have upgraded to Windows 10. I can't find SQL Server Configuration Manager. I have MSSQL 2008 and 2014 installed but there is no configuration manager in "All Apps".

This is just a picture of how I used to find it in Windows 8.1. 
In Windows 10 there is SQL Server Management Studio but there is no configuration like there was in Windows 8.1:

[image: Start menu application listing]

Comment: Did you try using Windows' Search?  Have you attempted a repair install of SQL?

Comment: I have tried with windows search, but I didnt try to repait installation.

Comment: Here's a detailed answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21759718/290343

Comment: I found it in: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft SQL Server 2014\Configuration Tools

Answer (score 112, accepted):

In later versions of SQL Server, the configuration manager is implemented as an MMC plugin.

There are two ways of accessing this:

1. Navigate to c:\windows\system32 and look for a file with the name SQLServerManager*nn*.msc, where *nn* is the version of SQL Server you have installed. For SQLServer 2014, the name is **SQLServerManager12.msc**. You can double-click on it and you'll see a result. You can also make a shortcut on the desktop if you like.
2. A much simpler way is to run the **Computer Management** applet from **Control Panel→Administrative Tools→Computer Management**, where you should find the configuration manager installed

[image]

Comment: In my Win10 machine I had to do: Right_Click on Windows Icon-->Control Panel-->System and Security-->Administrative Tools-->Computer Management-->SQL Server Configuration Manager

Comment: Be prepared to find 2 identical managers in the tree. One is for the latest, another is for one of the old versions. And it is no longer possible to change startup type. Thank you Microsoft for another drastic change in UI behavior! I hope that bad karma catches up with your execs soon.

Comment: This was dumb.  Why was it moved to such an obscure location?  Thanks, Microsoft.  :(

Comment: [Microsoft's intention](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2017) is for users to access the Configuration Manager via MMC by adding a snap-in. (Start, Run, "mmc", File, Add/Remove Snap-in..) IMHO, Computer Management is easier to use if you only have one version of Configuration Manager you need to access, otherwise utilize the snap-in.

Answer (score 17):

check this [microsoft doc page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager) for sql server configuration manager. 
snippet (May 2021):

```
SQL Server 2019     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager15.msc
SQL Server 2017     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager14.msc
SQL Server 2016     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager13.msc
SQL Server 2014     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager12.msc
SQL Server 2012     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager11.msc
```