# Where is the SQL Configuration Manager in SQL Server Management Studio 18?

Tags: windows-10, sql-server, ssms

I am setting up a new computer, a Surface Laptop 3.  I have installed SQL Server Management Studio 18.4, [downloading it from here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15).

I am just trying to install client tools and not the server software.

In past versions I believe this install has given me a file at `C:\Windows\SysWOW64SQLServerManager*.msc` where the asterisk is a number, depending upon which version I installed.  More info about this file  [in this question](https://superuser.com/a/1293322/10539).

However, that file was not installed on the machine and I cannot find any way to open the configuration manager.  I attempted to copy the file, 'SQLServerManager14.msc' over from another machine, but that got an error trying to open "MMC could not create the snap-in".

This might be because I have version 14, but the current version I need is 15, but that is just speculation.

If I download the full [developer edition of SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) and try to install only the client tools, I get redirected to the download above.

Internet searching on this one seems to send me in a loop with lots of outdated info, and most people think the above link should also install the control panel plugin.

Any ideas where I can go to install the SQL Server Config Manager?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver15) is part of [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) so in order to utilize it to manage the SQL Server protocols and such, you first need to install SQL Server as far as I know because it's part of and installed with the SQL Server instance installation procedure.

However, [SQL Server Management Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15) is a client tool which you can install onto a client which does not have any SQL Server instances running and use it to connect to and manage remote SQL Server instances.

### Supporting Resources

- [SQL Server Management Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver15)

---

### Additionally

To get the SQL Configuration Manager 2019, you'll need to download and run the [developer edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads), select "***New SQL Server Stand-alone installation or add features to an existing installation***" from the setup menu and then in the feature selection, select. . .

`Shared Features` => `Client Tools Connectivity`

Also consider selecting. . .

`Shared Features` => `Client Tools Backwards Compatibility`

[image]

Once that install completes, you should be able to find `SQLServerManager15.msc` file at `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` and access the **SQL Server Configuration Manager** to configure server aliases, etc.

Comment: I got it figured it out; you were right I needed to step through the SQL Server install.  This tool no longer comes with the client.  I updated the answer w/ a screenshot and marked it as complete.  Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for Developer 2017, I access it through Computer Management:

[image]

There, select  "Services and Applications"
[image]

And it's right there
[image]